# SQLAlchemy: How can I update the table in the database when I update the model in models.py

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have as SQLAlchemy model called `User` and I want to add another property to the class, ex: `address`.

I tried adding a new class property, and hoped that SQLAlchemy would realize there is a change in the class and would update the table automatically. That is not case.

I've looked online on how to make changes to the model which would then update the table automatically, but all I have found is `db.sessions` where they manually type out the changes they want to make. Is there a better way to update a model?

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    # new class property that I want to add
    address = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Yes I was able to get it working. I'm currently working with a friend so it was a little difficult to set flask-migrate for both of us but we eventually gitignored the migrations folder. Is it conventional to ignore the migrations folder. I just want to make sure I did it right?

Comment: No, it's definitely _not_ conventional to ignore the migrations folder. That should be shared. If one of you needs to modify the database schema, create a migration and add it to the repository. The migration should be applied "with" the code where it's required. For example, apply migrations when you switch branches. And you may need to reverse them when you go back. (Think about this: if you ignore the migrations folder, how do you and your friend maintain the same database schema? If you have different schemas, which should you use in production?)

Comment: How to do the same in Fastapi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of why [database migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) are important. Ideally, all of your data definition should be done using migrations.

Since you're already using Flask-SQLAlchemy, [Flask-Migrate](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate) is probably a good fit:

1. Add `Flask-Migrate` to your project's dependencies
2. Run `flask db init` to initialize migrations for your project (this is a one-time task)
3. Update your model (it sounds like you've already done this)
4. Run `flask db migrate` to generate a migration file (this should be done only as part of developing migrations)
5. Apply it with `flask db upgrade` (this will need to be done on each copy of the database when the new code is merged, i.e. on each development machine, in staging, in production, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm guessing the "db" in the command "flask db init" is from the \_\_init\_\_.py. If that's so then do I run the command in the \_\_init.py\_\_ directory?

Comment: `flask db` commands should be provided by `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and `Flask-Migrate`. You probably want to run those commands from the root of your repository.