# flask sqlalchemy - Anything I do I get IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

When I was using query on my database with flask-sqlalchemy I got an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: candidate.name
[SQL: INSERT INTO candidate (name, owner, contact_date, contact_year, contact_quarter, contact_month, status, position, final_result, country, seniority, exp_seniority, source) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Viktor Lacina', 'Beata Bilická', '2020-10-28', '2020', '2020/12-10', '2020/10', 'Invitation', "['developer']", '', 'CZ', '', '', 'Bea')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

I guess the reason was that attribute "name" was set as unique and probably was some duplicate in the data. A bigger problem is that when I tried to fix it in a database model (changed it in a code and ran flask db migrate) I got the same error.
The same happened when I tried to clear the database or even ran python from bash and tried to import model module.
I tried also to delete the database files directly in the system and initialize a new database but it also did not work, so I guess there are still some remaining connections.

Model definition was:

```
from web import db    

class Candidate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    owner = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    contact_date = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    contact_year = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    contact_quarter = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    contact_month = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    position = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    final_result = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    seniority = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    exp_seniority = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    source = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    interviews = db.relationship('Interview', backref='candidate', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Candidate {}>'.format(self.name)

class Interview(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    candidate_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('candidate.id'))
    interview_date = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    interview_year = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    interview_quarter = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    interview_month = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
    result = db.Column(db.String(32), index=False, unique=False)
```

After getting error for the first time I tried to change to:

```
class Candidate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
    # ...
```

but when tried to apply the change by flask db migrate + flask db upgrade I got the same error so the change have not been applied I guess.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to get from this, please?

Comment: What about your model definition ? Obviously the unique constraint is still there.

Comment: when I changed the model definition and tried to make it happen by "flask db migrate" and "flask db upgrade" it failed with the same integrity error.
Am I doing some stupid mistake?

Comment: I don't know, could you edit your question to add the model definition ?

Comment: sure it's there now

Comment: Something like this should be enough: `name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)`, but it does not look like the table definition was adapted. It is something you can confirm using a SQLite browser (or using sqlite straight from the command line). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56419785/6843158) help ? Note the `flask db upgrade`

Comment: Well the hint on the link reccomend the flask-migrate module that I am using and statements flask db migrate and flask db upgrade running any of them shows the same error to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am wondering if you are applying changes to the right database file. Could it be that you have a copy lying around somewhere in some other directory ? Because flask-sqlalchemy will create the database file on startup it doesn't exist. At the very least the last updated datetime of the file should change if the table definition is altered in any way.

Comment: Just found out there were some dependencies among my scripts that caused that program started running even after command flask db migrate. Now it works finally. Thanks for your help